# conditional filtering based on multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with the following columns & data:

```
ID    NAME    Amount              Date
53    GSG    -2,695,190,307.57    1/22/2018
53    GSG    -2,698,190,307.57    1/23/2018
77    GSG    -2,508,853,140.14    1/22/2018
77    GSG    -2,508,303,140.14    1/23/2018
76    GSG    -2,479,894,820.77    1/23/2018
53    MLG    -2,443,081,761.81    1/23/2018
53    MLG    -2,405,497,472.79    1/22/2018
67    GSG    -2,164,848,916.29    1/23/2018
66    GSG    -2,160,447,589.23    1/22/2018
66    GSG    -2,160,447,589.23    1/23/2018
76    MLG    -2,147,093,992.33    1/23/2018
```

The output I am looking for is whenever we have two consecutive dates for a specific scenario, we need to compare the amounts and for which ever date we have max amount, I want to display that record as the result. The expected result set should look like this:

```
ID    NAME    Amount              Date
53    GSG    -2,698,190,307.57    1/23/2018
77    GSG    -2,508,853,140.14    1/22/2018
76    GSG    -2,479,894,820.77    1/23/2018
53    MLG    -2,443,081,761.81    1/23/2018
67    GSG    -2,164,848,916.29    1/23/2018
66    GSG    -2,160,447,589.23    1/22/2018
76    MLG    -2,147,093,992.33    1/23/2018
```

I tried the case statement, here is the SQL that I have:

```
select hdc1.ID, hdc1.name, 
    case when hdc1.amount < hdc2.amount
        then hdc1.amount
        else hdc2.amount
    end as Final_amount,
    Case when hdc1.amount < hdc2.amount
        then hdc1.date
        else hdc2.date
    end as forecast_date,
from Hori_dmnd_cmo hdc1, Hori_dmnd_cmo hdc2
where hdc1.date = date(hdc2.date - 1 day)
    and hdc1.id = hdc2.id
    and hdc1.name = hdc2.name
```

Comment: What about the other two entries for `ID` 53?

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: ID NAME Amount Date
53 GSG -2,698,190,307.57 1/23/2018
77 GSG -2,508,853,140.14 1/22/2018
76 GSG -2,479,894,820.77 1/23/2018
53 MLG -2,443,081,761.81 1/23/2018
67 GSG -2,164,848,916.29 1/23/2018
66 GSG -2,160,447,589.23 1/22/2018
76 MLG -2,147,093,992.33 1/23/2018

Comment: Not as a comment, edit the question instead.

Comment: What is your question?  What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems on the right track, although I would use `join` instead of `,` -- and you get taking the minimum rather than the maximum.

Does this do what you want?

```
select hdc1.ID, hdc1.name, 
       (case when hdc1.amount >= hdc2.amount
             then hdc1.amount
              else hdc2.amount
        end) as Final_amount,
       (case when hdc1.amount >= hdc2.amount
             then hdc1.date
             else hdc2.date
        end) as forecast_date,
from Hori_dmnd_cmo hdc1 join
     Hori_dmnd_cmo hdc2
     on hdc1.date = (hdc2.date - 1 day) and
        hdc1.id = hdc2.id
        hdc1.name = hdc2.name
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. This helped in filtering some records but still some are not getting filtered correctly. Here are the items which are not filtered correctly:
1. when the amount is same for two dates, I only want to display first record. Currently it is displaying both
2. When the amount is less on the first day, it is displaying both

I think I need to update "hdc1.date = (hdc2.date - 1 day)" condition but not able to get it right.

Comment: @Dinesh . . . If you have multiple days in a row, then you can get multiple rows (your question doesn't specify what to do in that case).  With only two days, you should not be getting multiple rows.